# Using Index to build a range from a closed external workbook

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, external

Ideally we would like to avoid using VBA for this (if it's possible).

I have provided two sample spreadsheets to illustrate the issue as it's probably better with an example rather than giving confusing explanations.

- Main sheet: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjb5of65ru204y4/Main.xlsx?dl=0
- Suppliers sheet: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hcjzwatk2m67a94/Suppliers.xlsx?dl=0

Basically, we need to pull a range of an unknown length starting from an unknown offset from a closed workbook, then use `MATCH` to find the row index of a value we're looking for and return the value.

We tried three different methods. All formulas works when the workbook is open but we need a solution to use without the workbook open.

I didn't look into using `INDIRECT` since MS strictly states that `INDIRECT` is not compatible with closed workbook.

Here are the formulas with indentation for better visual:

**Method #1: Using index + count(if()) (array)**

This solution returns `#REF!` when the external workbook is closed

```
INDEX(
    INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$G:$G,
        MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
    )
    :
    INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$G:$G,
        MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
        +
        COUNT(
            IF('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A=$L$9,1)
        )-1
    )
    ,
    MATCH(
        K11,
        INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$D:$D,
            MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
        )
        :
        INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$D:$D,
            MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
            +
            COUNT(
                IF('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A=$L$9,1)
            )-1
        )
    ,0)
,0)
```

**Method #2: Using index + countif()**

This solution returns `#VALUE!` when the external workbook is closed

```
INDEX(
    INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$G:$G,
        MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
    )
    :
    INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$G:$G,
        MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
        +
        COUNTIF('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,$L$9))-1
    )
    ,
    MATCH(
        K11,
        INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$D:$D,
            MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
        )
        :
        INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$D:$D,
            MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
            +
            COUNTIF('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,$L$9))-1
        )
    ,0)
,0)
```

**Method #3: Using index + sumproduct()**

This solution returns `#REF!` when the external workbook is closed

```
INDEX(
    INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$G:$G,
        MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
    )
    :
    INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$G:$G,
        MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
        +
        SUMPRODUCT( -- ('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A=$L$9))-1
    )
    ,
    MATCH(
        K11,
        INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$D:$D,
            MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
        )
        :
        INDEX('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$D:$D,
            MATCH($L$9,'Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A,0)
            +
            SUMPRODUCT( -- ('Z:\...\[Suppliers.xlsx]suppliers'!$A:$A=$L$9))-1
        )
    ,0)
,0)
```

If I understand correctly, the tricky bit is building a dynamic range using `INDEX(ref,row,col):INDEX(ref,row,col)` since every bits works on their own but when used in this fashion it returns an error.

Note: You might need to update the absolute path to the spreadsheet `suppliers.xlsx` in `main.xlsx` if you download the provided demo

All help is gladly appreciated!

Comment: What about using `Get External Data` get query the suppliers data into Main?

Comment: I have never worked with these functions so I'm not too sure how to use this. While I have Excel 2019 I'm an old school Excel 2010 user. Following your suggestion I have tried `Data > Get Data > From File > From Workbook` then selected the workbook but **1)** The external workbook is now displayed in the main sheet, we would like to avoid that (probably doable with VBA) and **2)** none of the formulas have updated / display the right data (still errors). Can you elaborate a bit?